# Access id from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to acces the id from that array of objects..but i can't get it work.

```js
this.http.get<any> ('https://master.smartmedisys.gr:86/api/v1/medicines/barcode/2800449503104', {
    headers
  }).subscribe({
      next: data => {
          this.response = JSON.stringify(data);
          console.log(data);
          }
```

[image]

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show us your application code, and fuzzy images don't meet this site's standards.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: You need to use .parse, not stringify. `this.response = JSON.parse(data);`

Answer (score 1):

(Almost) anything in an **object** in JavaScript.

You can access the value for the **key** "id" of that dictionary by accessing `data`, but as pointed out by @mplungjan, how will depend on the type of your `data`:

If you believe `data` in an **object**:

```
this.http.get<any> ('https://master.smartmedisys.gr:86/api/v1/medicines/barcode/2800449503104', {
    headers
  }).subscribe({
      next: data => {
          this.response = data; // assuming the data is an object
          let id = data.result[0].data.id;
          console.log(id);
          //do something with id

          })
```

If you believe `data` is a **string**:

```
   this.http.get<any> ('https://master.smartmedisys.gr:86/api/v1/medicines/barcode/2800449503104', {
        headers
      }).subscribe({
          next: data => {
              this.response = JSON.parse(data); // assuming the data is a string
              let id = this.response.result[0].data.id;
              console.log(id);
              //do something with id
              })
```

Try both and see how it goes

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I tried it and i get thee error cannot read property result of undefined!

Comment: How did you name your JSON object after conversion, Andreas? Can you post the code of your conversion to JSON?

Comment: Nope. JSON is a [Text based data format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON). You can create a JSON STRING from an object by using JSON.stringify. There is not JSON.objectify, It is called JSON.parse and after parsing whatever you parse is no longer JSON

Comment: this.http.get<any>('https://master.smartmedisys.gr:86/api/v1/medicines/barcode/2800449503104', {headers}).subscribe({
        next: data => {
           this.response = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(data);

Comment: Ok Andreas, I have updated my answer. Try to adapt it to your needs and see if it works. The id extraction should work fine with the shown syntax

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `yourObject.result[0].data.id`?

You have a object with "result" attribute.
This "result" attribute is an array (with only one element, it seems).
This single element in the array have the "data" attribute.
This "data" attribute is an object with the "id" attribute you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I tried it and i get thee error cannot read property result of undefined!

Comment: @AndreasVasd try to get the whole result, first. Then the [0], step by step. A small example of yout code instead of only the data could help.